# How to write statement formally?

Tags: coq

I have natural number list and want to set hypothesis that head of list
cannot be zero,when l is nil. like (0::nil) gives false. How to write it
formally?I have error message ,when write it as

```
 ((h::nil)=?(0::nil))=false.
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you could use a match statement:

```
match xs with
 | 0::nil => False
 | _ => True
end
```